# Mongodb Import Error

Tags: mongodb, import

For the first collection: my first import was 1200 lines and it went fine. 
For the second collection: 
now i am trying to import ~121,500 lines of data in to mongodb. 
however, for the second collection i am getting an error:

[conn204] MapViewOfFile failed /data/db/mdc.6 errno:8 Not enough storage is available to process this command.

i cannot figure out if this is because of RAM or some registry issue.  I have 3 gigs of ram (win 32 bit) and 108 gigs of HDD space.  i have no other process taking up too much RAM (mongodb is around 900,000 kb and then Firefox at 200,000kb)

Answer (score 3):

If you're running the 32-bit version of MongoDB, you can only store about 2GB of data. Could it be that the data you're trying to import plus the data already in your MongoDB data path exceeds that?

In the 64-bit version there isn't a limit to the amount of data you can store, but you need a 64-bit CPU for that to run obviously.